# Xpath to get an the parent node where two attributes of a sub node have a particular value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

Given this dataset at: https://dd.weather.gc.ca/observations/xml/ON/today/today_on_20200129_f.xml

I think I am **not dealing with namespaces properly** but I am unsure what to do here.

How would I get the an om:member node where om:member/om:Observation/om:metadata/set/identification-elements/element/name=wmo_station_number and it's value is, for example 71704.

I have this:

```
    xml.Load(url);
    var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("om", "http://www.opengis.net/om/1.0");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("", "http://dms.ec.gc.ca/schema/point-observation/2.1");        
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("gml", "http://www.opengis.net/gml");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    nsmgr.PushScope();

    //  "Observation//element[@name='{identifier}']";
    var tmp = xml.SelectSingleNode("//om:member/om:Observation/om:metadata", nsmgr);
```

I know this is a half witted attempt but it seems as soon as I try anything without a namespace prefix I get errors or just nothing back.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `System.Xml.Linq`

```
string url = "https://dd.weather.gc.ca/observations/xml/ON/today/today_on_20200129_f.xml";
string om = "http://www.opengis.net/om/1.0";
string xmlns = "http://dms.ec.gc.ca/schema/point-observation/2.1";

var doc = XDocument.Load(url);
var members = doc.Root.Elements(XName.Get("member", om));
var member71074 = members.FirstOrDefault(x => x
                      .Element(XName.Get("Observation", om))
                      .Element(XName.Get("metadata", om))
                      .Element(XName.Get("set", xmlns))
                      .Element(XName.Get("identification-elements", xmlns))
                      .Descendants()
                      .Any(y => y.Attribute("name")?.Value == "wmo_station_number" && 
                                y.Attribute("value")?.Value == "71704"));
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll use it and upboat because it gets me the data I want. Still want to know what was wrong with what I was doing but this is nicer anyway.

Comment: @carny666 I made an update which lengthens the code but should improve performance, since using .Descendants() so early would check many more nodes than necessary. I'm afraid I'm not familiar on how to do it using XmlDocument

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath that should return the node.

```
//om:member/om:Observation/om:metadata/set/identification-elements/element[@name='wmo_station_number'][@value='71704']
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. for whatever reason this doesn't work for me. I mean it looks good. I've been playing with ones like that it seem as soon as I introduce an element name that has no prefix it returns null.

I think my problem has something to do with the namespace manager.

Comment: `I introduce an element name that has no prefix it returns null` you mean without `@` for `name` attribute?

Comment: I would think this would get me some data: //om:member/om:Observation/om:metadata/set but what I get is null. the set element doesn't have a prefix.

Comment: That's weird. I see the data when tried your `//om:member/om:Observation/om:metadata/set` xpath in the [xpath tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try :

```
//*[@name="wmo_station_number" and @value="71704"]/ancestor::om:member
```